# ¿Cómo cambiar el valor de un datepicker al dar clic automáticamente?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un input, que necesito que se muestre en formato datepicker, al seleccionar una fecha, ese valor lo envío como parámetro a una función.

Mi problema es que no captura el valor al seleccionar la fecha, es decir debo recargar la página para que la caja de texto tenga ese valor, y necesito que por cada selección de fecha el valor de la caja de texto cambie en automático.

Les comparto mi código.

HTML

```
            <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="6">
                    <tr style="border-collapse:separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="TXTInicio" class="form-control" placeholder="Inicio" />
                        </td>
                        <th> &nbsp;</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="TXTFin" class="form-control" placeholder="Fin" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TXTInicio").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    $("#TXTFin").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
     $("#TXTInicio").val("");
     $("#TXTFin").val("");

    });
```

Utilizo estos valores para realizar un filtro de búsqueda, al iniciar mi pagina limpio los valores de estas cajas, el problema es que no me los captura. Cuando quito estas lineas:

```
             // $("#TXTInicio").val("");
    // $("#TXTFin").val("");
```

y recargo la página, si me captura los valores, es decir es como si le diera el valor anterior. Ojalá alguien pueda apoyarme con este problema.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné de ésta manera, por si le llega a servir a alguien más algún día.

```
        $("#TXTInicio").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            finicio = dateText;        
        }
    });
```

"finicio" es una variable global que me almacena el valor del datepicker.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No utilices el $(document).ready(); sólo una función:

```
$(function() {
    $("#TXTInicio").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    $("#TXTFin").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el **.val()** de jquey no funciona en datapicker al momento de cambiarle el formato. Puedes utilizar la nuncio **setDate** de **datepicker**.

```
$("#TXTInicio").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).datepicker("setDate", "");
$("#TXTFin").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).datepicker("setDate", "");
```